# Calling UWP C++/CX dll from native Win32 C++ code

Tags: uwp, windows-10, interop

Is it possible to load and call functions in a C++/CX dll from a good-ol' win32 executable?

I guess I'm looking for an equivalent of C#/win32 interop services, but for C++/CX.

I'm targeting Windows 10.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Did you want to ask how to create a library for your UWP app to invoke? Or did you want to ask how to get notification when your UWP app get data from BLE device?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT - I want to ask if it's possible to call/be called by an UWP dll from a Win32 C++ native executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/CX and the WinRT APIs in general are not specific to UWP -- you can use [the `/ZW` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zw-windows-runtime-compilation) to enable the language extensions in a normal project.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can utilize C++/WinRT to call into WinRT/UWP components from ISO C++ source code (without C++/CX) precisely as you request.  Incrementally the official documentation for C++/WinRT is rolling out now, but alas the documentation is only partially completed (and the XAML compiler's support for C++/WinRT is not yet released).  In a nutshell, the reflection/etc that C++/CX did at runtime, cppwinrt.exe does at C++-code-generation-time prior to compiling your app's source code.  Plus C++/WinRT encapsulates/tames WRL with an easier-to-use(-than-WRL) value-semantics C++ class for each runtime-component-class to encapsulate all the ATL/COM-interworking machinery behind the scenes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis